# Troubleshooting MSSQL Connection from PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to connect to an external Sql Server through PHP 5.2.

Using this line:

```
$con = mssql_connect('123.123.123.123','Username','Password') or die('Could not connect to the server!');
```

I'm receiving this error:

> Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect
>   to server: 123.123.123.123 in
>   /home/file/public_html/structure/index.php on line 4 Could not connect
>   to the server!

My hosting provider assures me that ports are open for my server to connect to the DB. Looking at my php info, MSSQL Support is enabled, using FreeTDS.

Any ideas why this would be failing, or how I can begin trouble shooting the problem?

Comment: try to specify the port of the sql-server explicitly

Comment: follow the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php) for details about syntax

Answer (score 0):

i know that there is some security for remote connection to MSSQL.
i had a same issue.
you need to give connection permition for requested ip.

did you try to connect with your personal compter with a MS SQL program.

if you can so you have problem with your cilent (php host)

if you can not so you have problem with mssql server